# How to tell git which private key to use?

Tags: ssh, git, authentication, private-key

`ssh` has the `-i` option to tell which private key file to use when authenticating:

> `-i identity_file`
>
>   Selects a file from which
>     the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA authentication is read. 
>     The default is
>   `~/.ssh/identity`
>   for protocol version 1,
>     and
>   `~/.ssh/id_rsa`
>   and
>   `~/.ssh/id_dsa`
>   for protocol version 2. 
>     Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis
>     in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple
>   **`-i`**
>   options
>      (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

Is there a similar way to tell `git` which private key file to use on a system with multiple private keys in the `~/.ssh` directory?

Comment: See [this question in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4565700/247696) as well.

Comment: Also related http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: Don't mess around with all the host-based top-rated answers. See Dmytro Buryak's path-based answer instead.

Answer (score 1081, accepted):

In `~/.ssh/config`, add:

```
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

If the config file is new, check access permissions using

```
stat -c %a ~/.ssh/config
```

if returns NOT 600, you should do

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Now you can do `git clone git@github.com:{ORG_NAME}/{REPO_NAME}.git`

- Where `{ORG_NAME}` is your GitHub user account (or organization account)'s GitHub URI name.

  - Note that there is a colon `:` after `github.com` instead of the slash `/` - as this is not a URI.
- And `{REPO_NAME}` is your GitHub repo's URI name
- For example, [for the Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) this would be `git clone git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git`).

NOTE: On Linux and macOS, verify that the permissions on your `IdentityFile` are 400. SSH will reject, in a not clearly explicit manner, SSH keys that are too readable. It will just look like a credential rejection. The solution, in this case, is:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

Comment: What if you need to connect to the same host with different keys?

Comment: I'm using this trick in my [`github-keygen`](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) tool that I built to manage SSH keys and settings for Github.

Comment: @Cliff Nop, in my manpage: "`HostName`: Specifies the real host name to log into.  This can be used to specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts." My ssh version is openssh-6.7p1.

Comment: @Grissiom That's exactly what it says. But you seem to understand the meaning backwards. Host (or Match) is required. To create a host nickname you place the nickname in the Host line and the real hostname in the HostName line. Examples: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/creating-remote-server-nicknames-sshconfig/

Comment: If the config file is new, don't forget to do `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: User git perfact

Comment: Note you might not need "username" in your git path.  e.g. my user on our local gitlab with permission for our shared project is Alice, I'm logged onto Linux as Bob.  I created the ssh keys as Bob and put the public key on gitlab associated with Alice.  Now I can clone like this from Linux, logged in as Bob, without mentioning "Alice" anywhere,

Comment: OMG why wouldn't it just tell me that the rights are wrong... It said its wrong first (warned) and then I've changed it. It didn't tell me next time saying me just that permission is denied.

Comment: @ValentinKlinghammer the answer from @Flimm has the solution for this question. It is to use `core.sshCommand` git configuration. https://superuser.com/a/912281/162466

Comment: This worked for me - important to note that creating a directory inside `.ssh` and trying to organize keys inside directories would require to also change the permissions of that directory.

Comment: none worked for me...not sure why

Comment: This forces git to use a specific key for an entire domain, which usually won't work. For example, if someone has a personal github account as well as a work account, this configuration will break one of them.

Comment: Won't work with GIT LFS

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: The user option is not required since you're passing the user in the git clone command.

Comment: Regarding contacting the same host with different keys: Here it is essential to understand that in `.ssh/config` `Host` is a custom name you can give to the host specified under `HostName`. The `github.com` part in the git URL `git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git` refers to this `Host` and thus has to match it exactly. If you have a second Github ssh key, you can create a section `Host github2` in `.ssh/config` and then use the URL `git@github2:torvalds/linux.git` (see also https://superuser.com/a/1519694/96128).

Comment: @user905686 I have been trying to figure out how to support multiple keys with the same host FOREVER! Thanks a lot for this comment, I FINALLY got it working!

Answer (score 762):

### Environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

From Git version 2.3.0, you can use the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example" git clone example
```

Note that `-i` can sometimes be overridden by your config file, in which case, you should give SSH an empty config file, like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git clone git@github.com:example/example.git
```

### Configuration `core.sshCommand`

**Since Git version 2.10.0**, you can configure this per repo or globally, using the `core.sshCommand` setting. There's no more need to use the environment variable. Here's how you clone a repo and set this configuration at the same time:

```
git clone -c "core.sshCommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git@github.com:example/example.git
cd example/
git pull
git push
```

If the repo already exists, run:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null"
```

The configuration is saved in `.git/config`

Comment: I had  to export the *shell* variable to an environment variable to make this work, i.e. `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example"`, then `git clone example`

Comment: @Abdull In Bash, doing the assignment on the same line as the command exports the environment variable for just that command. Try it: `example=hello /usr/bin/env | grep example`.

Comment: things have become even better: as of Git 2.10, you can store the command in your Git configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/520162

Comment: For me I had to remove the ` -F /dev/null` i dont know why , otherwise it would tell me: `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/toptal_i
nterview_3_rsa -f /dev/null"
PS C:\Users\Mercurius\Desktop\timekeep> git push -u origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /dev/null: Name or service not known`

Comment: @Noitidart `/dev/null` is only a valid filename in UNIX-like operating systems, it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks very much @Flimm, so it is safe to do your command without the `-F` too? Also I don't understand in the second part, since 2.10.0 you mention we can configure it globally, but the second part only shows the local method no?

Comment: The `core.sshCommand` config setting was just the thing I needed, because it lets me use a certain key by default in most circumstances, but then specify a different key with a `core.sshCommand` in a `repository/.git/config` file for a specific repo.  Thank you!

Comment: If you need multiple keys, the -i parameter can be repeated, and ssh will try each key in turn. `git config core.sshcommand "ssh -i /path/to/keyA -i /path/to/keyB"`. This lets git use different keys with different remote hosts.

Comment: For git versions < 2.3, you can use `GIT_SSH` (see other answers).

Comment: For me `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` didn't work until I used [`IdentitiesOnly`](https://superuser.com/q/268776/55307), such as this command: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mysubdir/id_rsa -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'" git push`.

Comment: This is the best answer. The use of the environment variable via `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_otherkey"` is so handy and flexible. I don't like setting multiple github keys in configuration `.ssh/config` because I also have to alias the github url for example, `github.com` becomes `github.com.smeagol` just to differentiate and this alias URL becomes your git remote address.

Comment: This is especially useful when debugging git ssh. I can add -vvv to increase verbose mode.

Comment: Hi !! Do you know how to propagate this to a submodule?

Comment: Why are you adding the -F flag? To make sure no other config is used aside from the one explicitly mentioned?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić Yes.

Comment: With Windows that would be `-F nul`, but with OpenSSH one can use `-F none`

Comment: I spent hours looking for a solution and this was the easiest. Works like a charm for setting different ID files using a shell function by just setting the env var.

Comment: Useful answer. In addition, in Mac `-F /dev/null` is not required.

Comment: I really liked the `core.sshCommand` command. If you work in multiple projects, manually setting `.ssh/config` is not cool (and this file is not project specific). In my example, in a learn exercise on AWS CodeCommit: `git clone -c "core.sshCommand=ssh -l APKA2LOBFCDGHFO7Z3GQ -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/CloudWatchTriggerSNS`. After the clone and `cd` into project, you never need to specify user and key for this repo again: `git config --get core.sshcommand`, output `ssh -l APKA2LOBFCDGHFO7Z3GQ -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 192):

There is **no *direct* way** to tell `git` which private key to use, because it relies on `ssh` for repository authentication. However, there are still a few ways to achieve your goal:

### Option 1: `ssh-agent`

You can use `ssh-agent` to temporarily authorize your private key.

For example:

```
$ ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; git fetch user@host'
```

### Option 2: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

Pass the ssh arguments by using the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable
(Git 2.3.0+).

For example:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
  git clone user@host
```

<sub>You can type this all on one line — ignore `$` and leave out the `\`.</sub>

### Option 3: `GIT_SSH`

Pass the ssh arguments by using the `GIT_SSH` environment variable  to specify alternate `ssh` binary.

For example:

```
$ echo 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $*' > ssh
$ chmod +x ssh
$ GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_SSH='./ssh' git clone user@host
```

<sub>Note: The above lines are shell (terminal) command lines which you should paste into your terminal. They will create a file named *`ssh`*, make it executable, and (indirectly) execute it.</sub>

<sup>Note: [`GIT_SSH` is available since v0.99.4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4852f7232b7a83fbd1b745520181bd67bf95911b) (2005).</sup>

### Option 4: `~/.ssh/config`

Use the `~/.ssh/config` file as suggested in other answers in order to specify the location of your private key, e.g.

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: // , What if your identity in ssh-agent is forwarded, though, as in this question? http://superuser.com/questions/971732/how-do-i-undo-an-ssh-add-on-a-forwarded-identity-to-access-github

Comment: I've allowed me to reformat this post: IMO this is by far the most comprehensive answer. In its original design, a quick scan suggested the post where describing a single complicated solution to the problem, so I missed it.

Comment: `$ ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; git fetch user@host'` worked for me when nothing else would. Kudos.

Comment: I had to use `~/.ssh/config` method, env vars didn't work for me...

Comment: `GIT_SSH` is available since [v0.99.4 (August 2005)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4852f7232b7a83fbd1b745520181bd67bf95911b), so basically since Git exists (April 2005).

Comment: Tgus answer is outdated.

Comment: @pwned Which part?

Comment: @kenorb the part which doesn't suggest core.sshCommand

Answer (score 99):

Use custom host config in `~/.ssh/config`, like this:

```
Host gitlab-as-thuc  
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.thuc
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

then use your custom hostname like this:

```
git remote add thuc git@gitlab-as-thuc:your-repo.git
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, as I have separate GitHub accounts for home and work. I just had to set `Host work.github.com` `HostName github.com` `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work`, and then replace "github.com" by "work.github.com" whenever I clone a work repository. It still connects to "github.com", but using a non-default key pair.

Comment: The URL for details ("http://itblog.study.land/...") doesn't work any more :(

Comment: @CarlSmotricz the original one was moved here: https://medium.com/@thucnc/how-to-specify-different-ssh-keys-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain-bef56639dc02

Comment: FINALLY!!! This answer actually shows how you can utilize what you put in the `~/.ssh/config` file.  Every other answer misses how you can set the host when you add the origin, which automatically allows git to use the correct key file.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: +1 upvote great answer, it helped me also, I've used this and found this to work. 2 additional tips: 1) slightly different for bitbucket, repos are identified by project/repo-name, so my git `origin` looks like: `git@therobyouknow:therobyouknow/myproject.git` (where the first therobyouknow is the `Host` in `config` and the 2nd therobyouknow is the bitbucket project.

Comment: Tip 2) and essential: if you have other `Host *` also in your config, whereby you want to use that for all over remote machines, _except_ for your gitlab/bitbucket/github, then you need to make sure you _exclude_ that config from `Host *` and I did this by changing `Host *` to `Host !bitbucket.org` which meant that its config doesnt "bleed" into my bitbucket config. See [My comment here](https://superuser.com/questions/732231/how-can-i-apply-some-settings-to-a-ssh-hosts-excluding-one-other-host#comment2460460_732274)  to the original answer there I want to give credit for here for this idea

Comment: To clarify Tip 2) further: from what I've found, it does the same job as `Host * !bitbucket.org` (which itself _didn't_ work for me) but without the `*`, so what `Host !bitbucket.org`(which _did_ work for me) is saying is: " `Host *` - everything _except for_ `bitbucket.org` " - the `*` - meaning "everything", though absent, is still in effect and implied.

Comment: This is it. There's no git command hacks no nothing. This is it. *Thank you.*

Comment: This was particularly useful setting up a CICD pipeline that pulled multiple projects from github. Github insists on using a separate deploy key per project, and using these custom hosts is how I get the pipeline to use the right keys per project.

Comment: The full process is also documented on https://chasethedevil.github.io/post/github-and-ssh/ (which uses the same trick)

Answer (score 99):

If you need to connect to the same host with different keys then you can achieve it by:

1. Configure the `~/.ssh/config` with different Hosts but same HostNames.
2. Clone your repo using the appropriate host.

Example:

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host work
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
  User git
    
Host personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
  User git
```

Then **instead** cloning your repos like:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/my-work-project.git
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/my-personal-project.git
```

you must do

```
git clone git@work:username/my-work-project.git
git clone git@personal:username/my-personal-project.git
```

Comment: Or just `git remote add origin git@personal:username/my-personal-project.git`

Comment: This is hands down the way to do it especially if you use deployment keys in Github

Comment: Excellent. I didn't wanted to remember to modify the default cloning string, so as `host` I set the same that appears in the original cloning string and works perfect and don't have to clone anything again.

Comment: Or you can `git remote set-url origin git@personal:username/my-personal-project.git` for an existing project

Comment: TortoiseGit does not like this :(

Comment: @AdrianHerscu I believe it should be fine if your TurtoiseGit uses the same SSH client as git. See the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33328628/776546

Comment: Do you need the `User git` line if you're providing the user name in the URL (the `git@` part)?  Or if you want to keep that line, your URL can become `ssh://work/username/my-work-project.git` (with the user name coming from the SSH config file)

Answer (score 33):

Write a script that calls `ssh` with the arguments you want, and put the filename of the script in `$GIT_SSH`. Or just put your configuration in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: [Another explanation](http://superuser.com/a/355696/235231) of how to do this.

Comment: `~/.ssh/config` Is *the* way to go.

Comment: I work on a machine (A) from which I git push to a server (B) that only accepts ssh key authentication. While my ~/.ssh/config setup on (A) works perfectly fine when I work directly _on_ that machine, it does not when I login from some other location (C). Using `$GIT_SSH` and a script solved this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

If you do not want to have to specify environment variables every time you run git, do not want another wrapper script, do not/can not run ssh-agent(1), nor want to download another package just for this, use the git-remote-ext(1) external transport:

```
$ git clone 'ext::ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/alternate_id git.example.com %S /path/to/repository.git'
Cloning into 'repository'
(...)
$ cd repository
$ git remote -v
origin  ext::ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/alternate_id git.example.com %S /path/to/repository.git (fetch)
origin  ext::ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/alternate_id git.example.com %S /path/to/repository.git (push)
```

I consider this solution superior because:

- It is repository/remote specific
- Avoid wrapper script bloat
- Do not need the SSH agent -- useful if you want unattended clones/push/pulls (e.g. in cron)
- Definitely, no external tool needed

Comment: // , Excellent solution. I wonder, though, if this would allow one to specify an identity passed through using agent forwarding. Most of my keys are not local to the servers I am using them on. I asked about this here: http://superuser.com/questions/971732/how-do-i-undo-an-ssh-add-on-a-forwarded-identity-to-access-github

Comment: The answer deals only with a way of specifying arbitrary command lines to be used as git repositories. IMHO, you should try to sort out your issue using ssh alone first (e.g. "ssh _host_" should connect using the right key). I will try to provide more info on your other question, though.

Comment: Re my last comment, for some reason I cannot comment in your other question -- and do not have a concrete answer. Well, you might want to checkout http://serverfault.com/questions/599560/use-a-specific-forwarded-key-from-ssh-agent and the answer from user kasperd.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed to force Chef's `git` resource to use repository-specific deployment keys to clone/fetch from private Github repositories.

The additional advantage of this method over the environment/script based ones is that since the key-path is encoded in the working-repo's config, it will use the same key on both initial clone and subsequent fetches/pushes.

Comment: WOW! This is just great, didn't know about this. Thanks for the answer, quite helpful as well in puppet environments, to prevent the extra hassle to manage `.ssh/config` etc. +1!

Comment: Excellent answer! If you're using github, I made a quick guide about it: https://mattlebrun.com/use-different-git-ssh-key-per-project.html

Comment: This solution does not work together with the --recursive flag. The submodules are not fetched using the specified key and therefor fails if they require auth.

Comment: Each submodule is an entirely different repository, with their own set of remotes. They're glued together by Git for your convenience, but in no way remotes for a submodule are tied to the ones in the parent repository. I'm afraid that you must set the remote using the `ext` transport in _each_ submodule for recursion in the parent to work.

Comment: If you encounter the following error `fatal: transport 'ext' not allowed`, you have to whitelist the ext protocol via the `export GIT_ALLOW_PROTOCOL=ext`.
Basically, the git-remote-ext remote helper (which supports "ext::ssh example.com %S foo/repo" URLs) allows arbitrary command execution. This normally isn't ever a concern because user always sees and trusts the URL they pass to git. However git submodules, through the .gitmodules file, allow an attacker to request the client to fetch arbitrary git URLs.
https://hackerone.com/reports/104465

Comment: What is "git.example.com"? How would you use this with github or bitbucket, neither of which have a git.* subdomain?

Comment: This doesn't work when trying it with bitbucket, `git clone 'ext::ssh -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa_customkey git.bitbucket.org %S repo/project.git'` => `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: `git.example.com` is a placeholder host name. You must be able to ssh to the actual host for this to work, so I suggest you try ssh first using the specified key and get to the command line, double-check the actual path to the repository, and **only then** try to use the `ext` transport.

Comment: This is probably a good way, but my Git tries my default GitHub user, which has another key (GitHub wants unique-per-user keys). How can I make it use another user for other repo?

Comment: @OndraŽižka, you can add `-l USER` to the ssh command line to log in as user `USER`.

Answer (score 24):

This is my setup for multiple accounts, each using separate rsa key. It doesn't matter whether it's github, bitbucket, or whatever; this setup is not touching ssh client config, neither it uses hosts as selectors for configuration. It uses directory structure instead, and per-dir-subtree configurations.

```
$HOME/.gitconfig
[user]
  name = My Public Account Name
  email = my-public-email@public.com

[core]
  sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_public_account_id_rsa"

# public github user - IDEA
[includeIf "gitdir:~/idea/"]
  path = ~/idea/.gitconfig

# org-1 user
[includeIf "gitdir:~/idea/org-1/"]
  path = ~/idea/org-1/.gitconfig

# org-2 user
[includeIf "gitdir:~/idea/org-2/"]
  path = ~/idea/org-2/.gitconfig

# public github user - ruby
[includeIf "gitdir:~/rubymine/"]
  path = ~/rubymine/.gitconfig

# org-1 user
[includeIf "gitdir:~/rubymine/org-1/"]
  path = ~/rubymine/org-1/.gitconfig
```

And if I need to override key and user details for some projects, then I keep them in the same dir. And in that dir I create a ".gitconfig" file, like:

```
$HOME/idea/org-1/.gitconfig
[user]
  name = My Org-1 Account Name
  email = my-org1-email@org-1.com

[core]
  sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_org1_account_id_rsa"
```

Whenever I run any git command in `~/idea/org-1` directory or its sub-dirs, then it picks up my org-1 specific config and uses `my_org1_account_id_rsa` for ssh. And another name/email also for commits, not only rsa key.

This is hierarchical configuration, i.e. configurations are evaluated from more generic to more specific one. This is achieved by ordering  "includeIf" clauses in your `$HOME/.gitconfig` and having trailing slash in glob patterns, which results in adding `**` at the end. It's described nicely in documentation [gitconfig includeIf docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdircode). So keep in mind that **order matters**, and **glob patterns matter**.

Comment: Great, this worked super well for me as I already had git config files for work and personal projects.

Comment: Simplest way to achieve custom keys per project, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: This is absolutely the best answer going! Thanks

Comment: I liked it at first and it works in general -- although i used `[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@github.com:my-account/**"]`. However, `cloning` is not working with this nor is it with `gitdir`

Answer (score 18):

After my struggle with `$GIT_SSH` I would like to share what worked for me.

Through my examples I will assume you have your private key located at`/home/user/.ssh/jenkins`

### Error to avoid: GIT_SSH value includes options

```
$ export GIT_SSH="ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/jenkins"
```

or whatever similar will fails, as **git will try to execute the value as a file**. For that reason, you have to create a script.

### Working example of $GIT_SSH script `/home/user/gssh.sh`

The script will be invoked as follows:

```
$ $GIT_SSH [username@]host [-p <port>] <command>
```

Sample script working could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/jenkins $*
```

Note the `$*` at the end, it is important part of it.

Even safer alternative, which would prevent any possible conflict with anything in your default config file (plus explicitly mentioning the port to use) would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/jenkins -F /dev/null -p 22 $*
```

Assuming the script is in `/home/user/gssh.sh`, you shall then:

```
$ export GIT_SSH=/home/user/gssh.sh
```

and all shall work.

Comment: Thanks. Just note: use "$@" instead of $* for pass-thru arguments, as the former behaves correctly when arguments contain whitespace.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thanks for your note. However, I do not understand it completely - in zsh it helps me to keep strings with space in one piece, but in bash not. Can you tell me more or point to some explanation? I do not want to add some modification blindly.

Comment: You should remove the first half of your answer. No one's interested in a solution that doesn't work, and it's wasted reading that obfuscates the correct answer at the bottom, which works wonderfully.

Comment: @Cerin If you mean removing the "Error to avoid" I am going to keep it there. It shares common pitfall to avoid and it is very short. I am sure, someone would try optimizing the solution by providing all the things into variable (this happened to me), so I tried to shorten the path to success.

Answer (score 11):

So I set the GIT_SSH env variable to `$HOME/bin/git-ssh`.

In order to support having my repo configuration dictate which ssh identity to use, my `~/bin/git-ssh` file is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i $(git config --get ssh.identity) -F /dev/null -p 22 $*
```

Then I have a global git config setting:

```
$ git config --global ssh.identity ~/.ssh/default_id_rsa
```

And within any git repository I can just set a local `ssh.identity` git config value:

```
$ git config --local ssh.identity ~/.ssh/any_other_id_rsa
```

Voila!

If you can have a different email address for each identity, it gets even simpler, because you can just name your keys after your email addresses and then have the git config's user.email drive the key selection in a `~/bin/git-ssh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/$(git config --get user.email) -F /dev/null -p 22 $*
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a client that needed a separate github account.  So I needed to use a separate key just for this one project.

My solution was to add this to my .zshrc / .bashrc:

```
alias infogit="GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_specialkey\" git $@"
```

Whenever I want to use git for that project I replace "infogit" with git:

```
infogit commit -am "Some message" && infogit push
```

For me, it's easier to remember.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use ssh-ident instead of creating your own wrapper.

You can read more at:
  https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident

It loads ssh keys on demand when first needed, once, even with multiple login sessions, xterms or NFS shared homes.

With a tiny config file, it can automatically load different keys and keep them separated in different agents (for agent forwarding) depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you want to use `~/.ssh/config` for this. Simply pair server addresses with the keys you want to use for them as follows:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
Host heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.heroku
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`Host *` denotes any server, so I use it to set `~/.ssh/id_rsa` as the default key to use.

Answer (score 4):

I build on @shellholic and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command) with a few teaks. I use GitHub as an example and assume that you have a private key in `~/.ssh/github` (otherwise, see [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)) and that you added the public key to your GitHub profile (otherwise see [GitHub's help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)).

If needed, create a new SSH config file at `~/.ssh/config` and change permissions to 400

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Add this to the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

If you already have a remote set up, you may want to delete it, otherwise you may still be prompted for username and password:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then add a remote to the git repository, and notice the colon before the user name:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user_name/repo_name.git
```

And then git commands work normally, e.g.:

```
git push origin master
git pull origin
```

@HeyWatchThis on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command) suggested adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to prevent the SSH default behavior of sending the identity file matching the default filename for each protocol. See that thread for more information and references.

Comment: This was my mistake: "If you already have a remote set up...". Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

My solution was this:

create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY=dafault_key_to_be_used
PORT=10022 #default port...
for i in $@;do
   case $i in
    --port=*)
        PORT="${i:7}";;
    --key=*)KEY="${i:6}";;
   esac
done
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/${KEY} -p ${PORT}"
echo Command: $GIT_SSH_COMMAND
```

then when you have to change the var run:

```
. ./thescript.sh [--port=] [--key=]
```

Don't forget the extra dot!! this makes the script set the environments vars!! --key and --port are optional.

Answer (score 2):

All the information up to now (2020-01) are useful, but IMHO are a little bit messy, and no post sums them up to a clean solution.

So here are my solutions. If you are lucky with your current solution, then you are free to ignore this post.

**Overall Premise:**
Solution for *nix-based OS.
Tested on Debian-based OS, but should work on other *nix-based OS.

**Overall Prerequisites:**

- Separate identity files (keys) for different hosts and/or users available, e.g. generated via `ssh-keygen -f <filename> ...`

**Goals:**

- Use a specific identity file (key) per repository (optional: per host)
- Works with any host: GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc
- Simple to use and to adopt
- Prefer not messing around with URLs and use them as-is
- Prefer to use normal configuration of git and ssh
- (nice-to-have) Working in shell and gui tools
- (nice-to-have) Works with any tool: git, ssh, svn, rsync, etc.

**Solutions:**

1. Convenient tool [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ssh-ident/ssh-ident1)
2. Just normal git and ssh, with a minor portition of shell magic
3. Host renaming (also works with Putty/Pageant/Plink)

Note: A `Match Path` feature for OpenSSH would not help here, see https://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=141833748901966&w=2

**Solution #1 - Tool [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ssh-ident/ssh-ident1)**
Notes:

- Currently (as of 2020-01) I link my [own fork](https://github.com/ssh-ident/ssh-ident1) of the original [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident), as it gives more flexibility to argument and key filename matching.
- See docstring inside ssh-ident for how to use

*Prerequisites:*

- none

*Download and prepare*

- Download first to a project directory, then install to /usr/local/bin

  ```
  DLDIR="${HOME}/work/packages/ssh-ident"
  [ -d "${DLDIR}" ] || mkdir -vp "${DLDIR}"
  #
  #original: DLURL='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident/master'
  DLURL='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ssh-ident/ssh-ident1/dev'
  wget -P "${DLDIR}" -N "${DLURL}/ssh-ident"
  unset -v DLURL
  #
  install -v -D -t /usr/local/bin "${DLDIR}/ssh-ident"
  ## Debian base >=11 "bullseye": sed -i -e '1 s#\(\spython\)\(\s\|$\)#\13\2#' /usr/local/bin/ssh-ident
  #
  unset -v DLDIR
  ```

*Configure ssh-ident and the identities*

- Prepare files and directories

  ```
  [ -f ~/.ssh-ident ] || printf -- '\n' >~/.ssh-ident
  MYEXTRAIDENTITIES='1 gh2 dummy'
  for MYIDENTITY in ${MYEXTRAIDENTITIES}; do
    echo "${MYIDENTITY}"
    [ -d ~/.ssh/identities/"${MYIDENTITY}" ] || mkdir -vp ~/.ssh/identities/"${MYIDENTITY}"
  done
  chmod -v -R u=rwX,go= ~/.ssh/identities
  unset -v MYEXTRAIDENTITIES MYIDENTITY
  ```
- Maintain configuration of ssh-ident to detect GitHub repositories
  Example: ~/.ssh-ident

  ```
  ...
  MATCH_ARGV = [
    (r"\s(git@)?github\.com\s.*'my-git-user-1\/dummy\.git'", "dummy"),
    (r"\s(git@)?github\.com\s.*'my-git-user-1\/.+\.git'", "1"),
    (r"\s(git@)?github\.com\s.*'my-git-user-2\/.+\.git'", "gh2"),
    ...
    #
    (r"\s(git@)?gist\.github\.com\s.*'abcdef01234567890fedcba912345678\.git'", "1"),
    ...
  ]
  ...
  ```
- Copy private keys plus their public keys(!) to the corresponding identity directory
- Optionally create a per-identity ssh config file
  Example: ~/.ssh/identities/1/config

  ```
  Host github.com,gist.github.com
      IdentitiesOnly yes
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identities/1/github-user1.key
      User git
  ```

*Enable ssh-ident*

- Setup as ssh wrapper by installing as ssh via symbolic link to ssh-ident, either in /usr/local/bin for all users or in a user bin directory

  ```
  ln -s -T /usr/local/bin/ssh-ident ~/bin/ssh
  ```
- Testing ssh-ident config. Pass fitting parameters to the SSH call.

  ```
  ssh -vT git@github.com "test 'my-git-user-1/test-repo.git'"
  ```
- Use git as normal.

**Solution #2 - Just normal git and ssh**
*Prerequisites:*

- [git version](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) 2.10+

  - git config `core.sshCommand` (2.10+)
- [OpenSSH client version](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) 6.5+

  - function `Match` (6.5+)
  - option `IdentityFile none` (6.3+)
  - option `IdentitiesOnly` (3.9+)

*Concept:*
Use OpenSSH client config's `Match Exec` functionality to check for an environment variable (e.g. `SSHGITUSER`) to select a specific identity file (key).
Fail when environment variable is not set or contains an unknown user id.

Allows for the following options:

- One account on host: use `Host` block in OpenSSH client config to directly define the `IdentityFile` = pure vanilla ssh standard, no environment variable needed
- Multiple accounts on a host: pass the environment variable to the OpenSSH client, so it can react on it within `Match` blocks

  - Either set the environment variable directly in front of the git call (e.g. `SSHGITUSER='<id>' git ...`)

    - **Has to be used** when cloning a git repository (e.g. `SSHGITUSER='<id>' git clone ...`)
    - Works also for remotes that need different identity files (e.g. `SSHGITUSER='<id>' git fetch <remote>`)
    - Works also when using environment variables `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or `GIT_SSH` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode))
  - or use git config `core.sshCommand` to hard-code it for a repository (e.g. `git config --local core.sshCommand "SSHGITUSER='<id>' ssh"`)

    - Does **not** work for remotes that need different identity files
    - Does **not** work when using environment variables `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or `GIT_SSH` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode)) as these override git config `core.sshCommand` of the repository

*Setting up [OpenSSH client config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) ssh_config:*
Whenever we connect via ssh to a host, then we only want to connect with the identity files we explicitly specify. This can be achieved by setting `IdentitiesOnly` to `yes` and `IdentityFile` to `none` in a matching `Host` block, then no other identity files are offered to the target server, even when cached inside ssh-agent, nor the default key definitions will be tried.
If a default `Host` block exists for all servers, then extend its pattern to exclude the special host there.
Select the wanted identity file by checking an environment variable (e.g. `SSHGITUSER`). Define an id (number, letter or name) for each user and create a `Match` block for each id. The `Match` block should check the `Host` first to avoid using the identity file for other hosts and to avoid useless calls to the shell for testing the environment variable.
Specifing the user `git` for `github.com` and `gist.github.com` allows to remove `git@` from the URL. This setting is overriden when a user is defined in the URL.

Example ~/.ssh/config for GitHub:

```
...
### >>> GitHub
## use: SSHGITUSER='<id>' git ...
## optional: git config --local core.sshCommand "SSHGITUSER='<id>' ssh"
Host github.com,gist.github.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile none
    User git

Match Host github.com,gist.github.com Exec "test ${SSHGITUSER:-_} = '1'"
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1.key

Match Host github.com,gist.github.com Exec "test ${SSHGITUSER:-_} = 'gh2'"
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2.key

Match Host github.com,gist.github.com Exec "test ${SSHGITUSER:-_} = 'dummy'"
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-dummy-fake.key
### <<< GitHub
...
Host !github.com,!gist.github.com,*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal.key
...
```

Notes:

- If only a single identity file is used for a host, then in the related `Host` block change `IdentityFile` from `none` directly to the identity file and no `Match` blocks are needed.
- Remote `User` can also be set in a `Match` block. Remember a user in the URL overrides this setting.

*Testing ssh config:*
Pass the environment variable for the SSH call by defining it directly in front of the command.
Use a wrong user in the URL to avoid actual logins as we just want to see the identity files offered to the server.

```
SSHGITUSER='1' ssh -vT ssh-test-dummy@github.com
```

*Setting up git config of a repository for a hard-coded user id:*
To hard-code the user id to a repository use [git config `core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand) on the repository itself (via `--local`) to pass the environment variable to the ssh command.
The ssh command for git is either defined by the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (since git 2.3) or git config `core.sshCommand` (since git 2.10). If both are empty, then it normally defaults to just `ssh` (see Code funtions get_ssh_command() and fill_ssh_args() in [connect.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/connect.c)).
Special case is when cloning a repository, then there is no config for the not yet cloned repository, and the environment variable has to be set directly in front of the git call (e.g. `SSHGITUSER='<id>' git clone ...`).

Example:

```
SSHGITUSER='1' git clone git@github.com:my-git-user-1/test-repo.git ~/work/test-repo
```

```
cd ~/work/test-repo
git config --local core.sshCommand "SSHGITUSER='1' ssh"
# Test: git fetch
```

Notes:
When using environment variables `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or `GIT_SSH` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode)) these will override git config `core.sshCommand` of the repository.
Check first via `set | grep -e '^GIT_SSH'` and if any is set, then adapt from using environment variables to git config `core.sshCommand` of the user (via `--global`) and remove the GIT_SSH[_COMMAND] variable.
(e.g. `git config --global core.sshCommand "<content of used GIT_SSH[_COMMAND] variable>"`, plus `git config --local core.sshCommand "SSHGITUSER='<id>' <content of used GIT_SSH[_COMMAND] variable>"`)

*Other ideas for #2:*

- Use environment variable for `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-${SSHGITUSER}.key` or `User ${SSHGITUSER}`. Has the tendency to longer user ids.

*Setting up other tools for #2:*
On the command line just pass the environment variable by defining it directly in front of the command.
For hard-coding the user id the task is to find out how to pass the environment variable to the tool, e.g. configuration, wrapper script, alias, etc.

**Solution #99 - Host renaming**
*Prerequisites:*

- none

*Concept:*
As also mentioned in this thread you can rename the host as described in the [git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH) for the ssh config to recognize it, choose the identity depending on it and set the correct host name.
I normally do not prefer to mess up URLs instead of using configurations/variables.
Still I would then add the user id as a subdomain, e.g. `<user id>.github.com`.
After some talk adding the user id behind the host has the advantage that normally DNS resolution will fail as the TLD got messed up and therefore the connection will immediately fail also.
Extended the example for this, e.g. `github.com-<user id>`.

This also works for [Plink](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage-batch) and Pageant from Putty.
Putty checks for a saved session named like the "host", e.g. session `github.com-<user id>`. This can be used for this solution.
Then Putty checks for a session which references the host, e.g. session `testing` with host `github.com`. Just to let you know.

Example ~/.ssh/config for GitHub:

```
...
### >>> GitHub
Host github.com,gist.github.com,*.github.com,*.gist.github.com,github.com-*,gist.github.com-*
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        IdentityFile none
        User git

Host 1.github.com,github.com-1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1.key
        Hostname github.com

Host 1.gist.github.com,gist.github.com-1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1.key
        Hostname gist.github.com

Host gh2.github.com,github.com-gh2
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2.key
        Hostname github.com

Host gh2.gist.github.com,gist.github.com-gh2
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2.key
        Hostname gist.github.com

### <<< GitHub

Host !github.com,!gist.github.com,*
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal.key
...
```

Comment: Just for your interest: A `Match Path` feature for OpenSSH would not help here, see https://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=141833748901966&w=2

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` commands.

```
# create an agent
ssh-agent

# add your default key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# add your second key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<your key name>
```

After executing the above commands, you can use both keys as same time.
Just type

```
git clone git@github.com:<yourname>/<your-repo>.git
```

to clone your repository.

You need to execute the above command after you reboot your machine.

Comment: Please explain the process including How can I create an agent

Comment: Sounds smart, - but maybe a little to good to be true, considering how clumbsy all the other answers are. I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: @Zeth You may have a problem when creating the ssh agent. If you are using MacOS, you only need to execute `ssh-agent`. If you are using Linux, I suggest you read this article https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

While the question doesn't request it, I am including this answer for anyone else looking to solve the same problem just specifically for [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab).

## The gitlab solution

I tried using the [environment-variables](/questions/tagged/environment-variables) approach, but even [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) recommends using `~/.ssh/config` for anything more than the simple case. In my case I am pushing to a [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab) server - and I wanted to do so as a specific user - which is of course defined by the [private-key](/questions/tagged/private-key) during [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication) and not the username `git`. Once implemented I simply perform the following:

```
~/myrepo> git mycommit -m "Important Stuff"
~/myrepo> git mypush
[proceed to enter passphrase for private key...]
```

## Setup

Recall the location of your [private-key](/questions/tagged/private-key) `/myfolder/.ssh/my_gitlab_id_rsa` in my case.

Add an entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitlab-delegate
    HostName gitlab.mydomain.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /myfolder/.ssh/my_gitlab_id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Add the [git-alias](/questions/tagged/git-alias) in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
mypush = "!f() { \
           path=$(git config --get remote.origin.url | cut -d':' -f2); \
           branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); \
           git remote add gitlab_as_me git@gitlab-delegate:$path && \
           git push gitlab_as_me $branch && \
           git pull origin $branch; \
           git remote remove gitlab_as_me; \
         }; f"
```

As a bonus, I [perform my commits on this same host as a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841156/1808261) with this [git-alias](/questions/tagged/git-alias):

```
mycommit = "!f() { \
             git -c "user.name=myname" -c "user.email=myname@mysite.com" commit \"$@\"; \
           }; f"
```

## Explanation

All of the above assumes the relevant remote is `origin` and the relevant branch is currently checked out. For reference I ran into several items that needed to be addressed:

- The solution requires creating a new remote `gitlab_as_me`, and I didn't like seeing the extra remote [hanging around in my log tree](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun) so I remove it when finished
- In order to create the remote, there is a need to generate the remote's url on the fly - in the case of gitlab this was achieved with a simple bash [cut](/questions/tagged/cut)
- When performing a push to `gitlab_as_me` you need to be specific about what branch you are pushing
- After performing the push your local `origin` pointer needs to be "updated" in order to match `gitlab_as_me` (the `git pull origin $branch` does this)

Answer (score 1):

```
    # start :: how-to use different ssh identity files

    # create the company identity file
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "first.last@corp.com"
    # save private key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.corp, 
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.corp.pub # copy paste this string into your corp web ui security ssh keys

    # create your private identify file
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@gmail.com"
    # save private key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me, note the public key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me.pub
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me.pub # copy paste this one into your githubs, private keys

    # clone company internal repo as follows
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.corp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    git clone git@git.in.corp.com:corp/project.git

    export git_msg="my commit msg with my corporate identity, explicitly provide author"
    git add --all ; git commit -m "$git_msg" --author "MeFirst MeLast <first.last@corp.com>"
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.corp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    git push 
    # and verify 
    clear ; git log --pretty --format='%h %ae %<(15)%an ::: %s

    # clone public repo as follows
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.corp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    git clone git@github.com:acoolprojectowner/coolproject.git

    export git_msg="my commit msg with my personal identity, again author "
    git add --all ; git commit -m "$git_msg" --author "MeFirst MeLast <first.last@gmail.com>"
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    git push ; 
    # and verify 
    clear ; git log --pretty --format='%h %ae %<(15)%an ::: %s

    # stop :: how-to use different ssh identity files
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already a great many proposed solutions here, including numerous options working around the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable, many of which I've actually used myself over the years.

However, I would like to share a much simpler process that I recently discovered, using only [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/).

My personal favourite point of this method: it requires no modification of any Git config files, but it also won't *conflict* with any modifications you may want/need/have..

---

> Note: I'm going to approach this with one "primary" SSH key to use by default, and one "secondary" SSH key to use for specific projects. This will fit in well with doing "work" things on a "personal" machine, or vice versa, as well as extending to any additional "special" SSH keys you may need.
>
> Also, I should note that I use this for both GitHub and GitLab, with a "work" and "personal" SSH keys on each platform, from multiple separate computers, and it "Just Works"(tm).

The following steps do make a few assumptions here:

- you're running in a Unix-like environment (Linux, macOS, WSLv2 on Windows)
- primary SSH key in `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`
- secondary SSH key in `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal`
- work workspace in `~/workspace`
- personal workspace in `~/personal`

With that in place, the configuration process itself is dead simple:

1. install `direnv`, ensure it's loaded by `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`.profile`/etc.
2. create a file at `~/personal/.envrc` with `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal"`
3. open terminal at `~/personal`

- at this point, you might see a message like `direnv: error /Users/$USER/personal/.envrc is blocked. Run` direnv allow `to approve its content`. **note:** you will see this message every time the target `.direnv` file is modified.

At this point, navigating *into* `~/personal` in your terminal (or any subfolder, even directly) will load environment variables from `.envrc`, and navigating *out* to anywhere else will unload them.

---

Here's an example of this in action on macOS running ZSH enhanced with OMZ (bonus: OMZ comes bundled with a `direnv` plugin, which adds the binary to your `$PATH` and shows it's "active" status in your terminal window):

```sh
 ~ ------------------------------------------------------------------- 11:00:33 
> cd workspace 

 ~/workspace --------------------------------------------------------- 11:00:39 
> echo $GIT_SSH_COMMAND


 ~/workspace --------------------------------------------------------- 11:00:40 
> cd ../personal       
direnv: loading ~/personal/.envrc
direnv: export +GIT_SSH_COMMAND

 ~/personal ------------------------------------------------- direnv | 11:00:47 
> echo $GIT_SSH_COMMAND
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal

 ~/personal ------------------------------------------------- direnv | 11:00:49 
> cd ..
direnv: unloading

 ~ ------------------------------------------------------------------- 11:00:52 
> echo $GIT_SSH_COMMAND


 ~ ------------------------------------------------------------------- 11:00:53 
>
```

Hope this helps some people.. (:

Answer (score 1):

Before calling your usual git commands run:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_spesific_private_key
```

Comment: You answer is really short for a very old question that has many documented answers.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers above are correct, but they all fail, when using something like terraform

Imaginge this scenario

1. You have a personal github account
2. You join a new company, and create another github account with your work email

If you follow the instructions above, in 99% of the time, they will work. However, let's say you use terraform, with private git repos, and you have terraform modules and all of these modules are defined as

```
module "module_name" {
  source                     = "git@github.com:company/terraform-modules-repository.git//module_name?ref=v1.0.1"
  ..
}
```

Then when terraform tries to fetch these modules, they will fail. This is the problem.

Your constraints are

1. You cannot modify the source code
2. You will have to swap your private and work keys in your ssh config

See the problem?

Here is a better solution, that will work for many combinations

1. You define a gitconfig, that allows you to override your gitconfig
   See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig                              
[user]
    email = name.surname@gmail.com
    name = Name Surname
[includeIf "gitdir:**/company_name/"]
    path = ~/.git-preferences/work/company_name/.gitconfig
```

2. Inside of your preferences file for your company you add your ssh key to be used

```
$ cat ~/.git-preferences/work/company_name/.gitconfig
[user]
    email = name.surname@company.com
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/namesurname-company
```

3. With terraform specefically, it ignores the ssh command in the git config, and it will only work if you set the env variable https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19232
   Therefore you will also need to issue the command

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/namesurname-company"
```

This is the only way that I could get it working for all cases

Answer (score 0):

I'm using git version 2.16 and I don't need a single piece of script not even a config or modified commands.

- Just copied my private key to .ssh/id_rsa
- set permissions to 600

And git reads to key automatically. I doesn't ask anything and it doesn't throw an error. Just works fine.

Comment: Did you notice that the question is about “a system with multiple private keys in the ``~/.ssh`` directory”?

Answer (score 0):

> When you have multiple git account and you want different ssh key
>
> You have to follow same step for generating the ssh key, but be sure
> you

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C your-email-id@gmail.com
```

Enter the path you want to save(Ex: my-pc/Desktop/.ssh/ed25519)

Note: ed25519 is the folder name

Add the public key to your gitlab ([How to adding ssh key to gitlab](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair))

> You have to new ssh identity using the below comand

```
ssh-add ~/my-pc/Desktop/.ssh/ed25519
```

Comment: (1) Are you quoting somebody or something? If so, please identify the source. If not, please don’t use quote formatting.  (2) What is “ed25519”? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2"
```