# How do I configure SSH so it doesn't try all the identity files automatically?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, authentication, private-key

I have been putting my ssh identity files inside my `~/.ssh/` folder. I have probably about 30 files in there.

When I connect to servers, I will specify the identity file to use with something like

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/client1-identity client1@10.1.1.10
```

However, if I do not specify an identity file, and just use something like this:

```
ssh user123@example.com
```

I get the error

```
Too many authentication failures for user123
```

I understand that is because if no identity file is specified, and ssh can find identity files, then it will try all of them.

I also understand that I can edit the `~/.ssh/config` file and specify something like:

```
Host example.com
PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password
```

in order to prevent that connection from trying known identity files.

So, I guess I could move my identity files outside of the `~/.ssh/` directory, or I could specify each host that I want to disable identity-file authentication for in the config file, but is there any way to tell SSH by default not to search for identity files? Or to specify the ones it will search for?

Comment: Re "I understand that is because..." - use `ssh -v` to find out for sure.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can use the `IdentitiesOnly=yes` option along with `IdentityFile` (see [ssh_config man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)). That way, you can specify which file(s) it should look for.

In this example, ssh will *only* look in the identities given in the ssh_config files + the 4 ones listed on the command line (the identities provided by the agent will be ignored):

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes \
    -o IdentityFile=id1.key \
    -o IdentityFile=id2.key \
    -i id3.key \
    -i id4.key \
    user123@example.com
```

The forms `-i` and `-o IdentityFile=` are interchangeable.

In `.ssh/config`, you can include config like this:

```
Host example
User user123
Hostname example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example2
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: An [example](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/e01ac25450df5521d6fa) would be nice

Comment: @DimitriosMistriotis According to the ssh_config man page, either is acceptable: `Configuration options may be separated by whitespace or optional whitespace and exactly one '='; the latter format is useful to avoid the need to quote whitespace when specifying configuration options using the ssh, scp, and sftp -o option.`

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly` may not always work, you may have to exclude a host specifically; see https://superuser.com/questions/859661/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-ignore-the-identityfile-listed-in-host-for-one-specif

Comment: **If your SSH agent is still prompting you for a password, see [the answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1215488/59271).

Comment: This is counterintuitive. the ``identity_file`` man page option should mention that it is possible that the supplied key will not be used at all.

Comment: Note that the value in `Host` is not arbitrary. I just spent an hour debugging my SSH config until I realized that instead of using `Host some-cute-name` and `Hostname my-domain.com`, I had to set `Host my-domain.com` (then I removed the `Hostname` item since it was redundant).

Answer (score 127):

[user76528's short answer](https://superuser.com/a/268777/992857) is correct, but I just had this problem and thought some elaboration would be useful. You might also care about this solution if you've wondered "Why is ssh ignoring my identityfile configuration option"?

Firstly, unlike every other option in ssh_config, ssh does not use the first `IdentityFile` that it finds. Instead the `IdentityFile` option adds that file to a list of identities used. You may stack multiple `IdentityFile` options, and the ssh client will try them all until the server accepts one or rejects the connection.

Second, if you use an ssh-agent, ssh will automatically try to use the keys in the agent, even if you have not specified them with in `ssh_config`'s `IdentityFile` (or `-i`) option. This is a common reason you might get the `Too many authentication failures for user` error. Using the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option will disable this behavior.

If you ssh as multiple users to multiple systems, I recommend putting `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your global section of `ssh_config`, and putting each `IdentityFile` within the appropriate Host subsections.

Comment: nicely explained, thank you. It's not obvious that that parameter 'IdentitiesOnly' means *TakeOnlyWhatIExplicitlySpecifyThenFailoverToPassword*. And apparently, the ./ssh/id_rsa key is still listed.

Comment: Putting `IdentitiesOnly yes` in the global section of ssh_config is what did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. I used to use ('\' for newline) `Host * \ IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey` as a configuration option, and at first it seemed odd that having a different entry for a specific site, e.g. `Host special \ IdentityFile ~/.ssh/specialkey \ IdentitiesOnly yes` continued to supply `mykey` instead of `specialkey`. It certainly was unclear, until I realized (from your answer) that the IdentityFile entries are stacked in an order of evaluation and the last-defined one will be used. Removing `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey` solved the issue, and the correct, single key was used.

Comment: Before I tried this, I noticed my `git pull/push` commands were trying every single identity loaded in my agent. It wasn't a problem till at one point I had too many keys.

Comment: Thank you. Limiting my key to specific hosts rather than the global was the only thing that made ssh use the correct key for me, despite specifying it. It seems the order in which keys are added to the ssh-agent takes precedence over the order of the keyfiles in the ssh config when iterating this stack.

Answer (score 49):

I generally do it like so:

```
$ ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null -i ~/path/to/some_id_rsa root@server.mydom.com
```

The options are as follows:

- `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` - tells SSH to only use keys that are provided via the CLI and none from the `$HOME/.ssh` or via ssh-agent
- `-F /dev/null` - disables the use of `$HOME/.ssh/config`
- `-i ~/path/to/some_id_rsa` - the key that you explicitly want to use for the connection

#### Example

```
$ ssh -v -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null -i ~/my_id_rsa root@someserver.mydom.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug1: Connecting to someserver.mydom.com [10.128.12.124] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA f5:60:30:71:8c:a3:da:a3:fe:b1:6d:0b:20:87:23:e1
debug1: Host 'someserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/sammingolelli/.ssh/known_hosts:103
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to someserver.mydom.com ([10.128.12.124]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Tue Dec  8 19:03:24 2015 from 153.65.219.15
someserver$
```

Notice in the above output that `ssh` has only identified the `my_id_rsa` private key via the CLI and that it uses it to connect to someserver.

Specifically these sections:

```
debug1: identity file /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa-cert type -1
```

and:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/sammingolelli/my_id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only complete solution. Apparently, `-F /dev/null` is the missing piece in the other answers.

Comment: On Windows the equivalent for `/dev/null` is `NUL`. Yes, with only one "L".

Comment: Haven't checked when it was added, but there is now the `-F none` switch to `ssh`, which should have the effect same or similar to `-F /dev/null`.

Answer (score 18):

In the scenario where you have many keys, you will invariably run into the "Too many Authentication Failures" error.  If you have a password, and want to simply use the password to login, here is how you do it.

To use ONLY password authentication and NOT use Public-key, and NOT use the somewhat misleading "keyboard-interactive" (which is a superset including password), you can do this from the command line:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password user@example.com
```

Answer (score 18):

### Use IdentityFile but Keep Using ssh-agent to Avoid Passphrase Reprompts

The accepted solution of using `IdentitiesOnly yes` means you'll never be able to take advantage of ssh-agent, resulting in repeated prompts for your passphrase when loading your key.

To keep using `ssh-agent` and avoid the 'Too many authentication failures' errors, try this:

1. Remove any interactive console startup scripts that automatically load keys into `ssh-agent`.
2. add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to your client's ssh config. This will prompt you for the passphrase on first connect, but then add the key to your agent.
3. use `ssh-add -D` when you get 'too many authentication' errors. This simply 'resets' (deletes) your ssh-agent cache. Then attempt the connection again within the same session. You will be prompted for a passphrase, and once accepted, it will be added to your agent. Since you'll have only one key in your agent, you will be allowed to connect. ssh-agent is then still there for future connections during the same session to avoid reprompts.

   ```
   Host ex example.com
      User joe
      HostName example.com
      PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
      IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
      AddKeysToAgent yes
   ```

Comment: Will at accept keys added to keychain?

Answer (score 9):

add this at the end of `~/.ssh/config` file to prevent use keys for non config servers:

```
Host *
IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

Answer (score 8):

The ssh client and the `ssh-agent` is communicating through a Unix domain socket whose name is specified to the client by the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable (set by the agent upon its startup).

Thus, to prevent a single invocation of the client from querying the agent this variable can be set explicitly to something invalid, like an empty string;

```
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh user@server
```

A client invocation like this will fail communicating with the agent and only be able to offer the identities available as files in `~/.ssh/`, or any specified on the command line using `-i`, to the server.

```
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Connection refused
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It's simple and works when you're using commands that use SSH "under the hood", like git. A pity I can't upvote it more.

Comment: +1 **Set `IdentityAgent` to `none`** if you need to set this in your config file.

Comment: @user541686 Nice, this works a lot better for me than `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i …` in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

You had the answer all along (almost):

```
Host *
PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password
```

Worked for me.

Comment: The question asked about how to limit which public keys are used. This answer disables public key authentication entirely.

Answer (score -2):

All answers to this question focus on enforcement options of SSH. Actually, there is a much simpler way: do not keep your keys in `~/.ssh` folder. Just keep them elsewhere, e.g. in `~/.ssh/my_keys/`. Then your SSH client won't bother trying any unexpected keys, just do not store your keys in a folder, where it *expects* the keys to try to be stored.