# How does ssh choose the correct key to use?

Tags: authentication, ssh

How does `ssh-agent` understand which key should it use for which remote server?

I've came across different questions and posts that touches this topic somehow, but it still remain unclear to me.

What I have found is that if you want to use different ssh keys you need to use `-i` option and specify path to needed key or you can setup Identity files that specifies which key pair for which host to use.

But does it mean that by default `ssh-agent` can use only one key pair and it will try to use it for all remote servers?

Comment: Aren't the keys labeled by IP/name?

Comment: Related with detailed answers http://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-dosent-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But does it mean that by default `ssh-agent` can use only one key pair and it will try to use it for all remote servers?

By default, `ssh-agent` will use all the keys added to it to all the servers you connect. You can limit the keys by `ssh_config` as in the other answer.

The keys have fingerprints, but in the first phase of public key authentication, the public parts are just verified against the server list and if they do not match, authentication is skipped (usually to other key or password authentication).

Comment: To see this, run your SSH client with the -v verbose option.

Answer (score 5):

SSH supports a [`~/.ssh/config` file](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE) that allows you to specify different keys for different hosts. So you could have

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
Host example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example.key
```

There's a  [good tutorial on this functionality here.](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Answer (score -3):

The 'key' (no pun intended) is based upon the fingerprint as specified in [RFC4716](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt). As explained in ssh's man page:

```
When connecting to a server for the first time, a fingerprint of the
server's public key is presented to the user (unless the option
StrictHostKeyChecking has been disabled).  Fingerprints can be determined
using ssh-keygen(1):

           $ ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

If the fingerprint is already known, it can be matched and the key can be
accepted or rejected.
```

In an ASCII nutshell here is [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) explained with regards to which key is chosen/used:

```
ssh-keygen yourfingerprint
you ssh --> server (stores your fingerprint)
you ssh --> millions of other servers
you ssh initial server --> server --> Have I seen this fingerprint before?
```

**ADDED**

Because I hit enter too prematurely, the fingerprints are stored in:

```
~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: the start makes sense. The end does not answer the question in any point and is just nonsense.

Comment: This is about half correct for SSH *server* keys, but completely irrelevant to SSH *client* keys, which is the subject of this question.