# Why SSH always using first key accepted by server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

I have three SSH key pairs that can be found via `ssh-add -L`; two keys are accepted by the remote server, but only one key can be used for GitHub, and I want to clone a GitHub repository via agent forwarding *(hosting limits prevent deploy keys from working)*.

- The following can't log into GitHub and I found SSH perhaps uses the first key [`id_rsa`] listed via `ssh-add -L`, ignoring my `-i` command, so agent forwarding only works after deleting key `id_rsa`:

  ```bsh
  ssh -A -tt -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github user@ip 'ssh -T git@github.com'
  ```
- I [tried](https://superuser.com/a/268777/1252365) adding `IdentityFile` and `IdentitiesOnly` to `~/.ssh/config`, but it was also unsuccessful

Is this normal behavior and how do I force SSH to use a specific key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's normal. The agent already knows some keys. Then `-i` is an option of `ssh`, it doesn't directly affect the agent. When asked, `ssh` can add a key to the agent, but there is no straightforward way for it to remove keys or change their order. Moreover the agent is designed to serve to many clients. Some of them may need the keys you want to "hide" from this particular `ssh` connection. You need a somewhat different approach.

Run the local `ssh` as a subprocess of a *dedicated* agent and let `ssh` add the desired key to the agent. This way the key will be the only one known to the relevant agent. Processes that use the general purpose agent (if any) will not be affected.

```bsh
ssh-agent ssh -A -tt -o AddKeysToAgent=yes -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github user@ip 'ssh -T git@github.com'
```

From [`man 1 ssh-agent`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-agent#DESCRIPTION):

> `command [arg ...]`
> If a command (and optional arguments) is given, this is executed as a subprocess of the agent. The agent exits automatically when the command given on the command line terminates.
>
> […]
>
> […] The agent starts a command under which its environment variables are exported […]
>
> […]
>
> […] `ssh(1)` looks at these environment variables and uses them to establish a connection to the agent.
>
> The agent initially does not have any private keys. Keys are added using `ssh-add(1)` or by `ssh(1)` when `AddKeysToAgent` is set in `ssh_config(5)`. […]

From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#o):

> `-o option`
> Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration file.

From [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#AddKeysToAgent):

> `AddKeysToAgent`
> Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running `ssh-agent(1)`. If this option is set to `yes` and a key is loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the default lifetime, as if by `ssh-add(1)`.