# Tell git which private key to use for a user without home folder

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

I was reading the question [Tell git which private key to use](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/tell-git-which-private-key-to-use), and the answer doesn't apply for a case were the user doesn't have any home directory.

We're setting up a Jenkins server right now, and the user who run Jenkins doesn't have any home folder. But that particular user must access a GIT repository.

How can the user running GIT use a key authentication?

Comment: // , What if the machine doesn't even have the key in question? Can one specify which forwarded identity to use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The environment variable GIT_SSH tells git what ssh exectutable to use.  So you could create a script something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/identity.file "$@"
```

Then chmod it executable, and set GIT_SSH=/path/to/sshscript

Comment: advancing to the next roadblock: my ssh client then tries to update known_hosts and that fails!

Comment: @GLRoman The UserKnownHostsFile option let's you specify where the file should be