# How to undo a global RemoteCommand config on a specific host in ssh config file

Tags: linux, ssh

I have the following `~/.ssh/config` file :

```
Host myserver1
    Hostname myserver1.blop.com
    User blup

Host myserver2
    Hostname myserver2.blop.com
    User blup

Host bitbucket.org
    RemoteCommand # Want to not take care of global RemoteCommand
    RequestTTY no

Host *
    User root
    RemoteCommand PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\007"' $SHELL;
    RequestTTY yes
```

I want a default `RemoteCommand` on all server that change PROMPT_COMMAND on remote shell after login. (this is working)
The `RemoteCommand` option make connections to bitbucket (git) fail and I didn't find a way to disable `RemoteCommand` for a specific host.

Tried : Nothing, Empty string `""`, `$SHELL;`

Any idea ? There is a default `RemoteCommand` value to restore ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `none` as `RemoteCommand` value.

```
Host bitbucket.org
    RemoteCommand none
    RequestTTY no
```

2. An [Alternative approach](https://superuser.com/a/732274) is to simply exclude bitbucket.org from default Host config :

```
Host * !bitbucket.org
    User root
    RemoteCommand PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\007"' $SHELL;
    RequestTTY yes
```

3. [Better solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451534), for my specific problem with `RemoteCommand`, add a `Match` to only apply settings for `ssh` commands:

Simply add this at top of file

```
Match exec "test $_ = /usr/bin/ssh"
    RemoteCommand PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\007"' $SHELL;
    RequestTTY yes
```